# How to HTML special chars using the xmlhttp.open?

Tags: javascript, php

Please bear with me as I am a newbie programmer. Is their a way that HTML special chars can be used in call as this one: `xmlhttp.open("POST","login/login.php",true);`
because when I check my URL adding this

`/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E`

turns

`/"><script>alert('hacked')</script>`

that somebody says my website can be exploit.

Can somebody help me or link a to similar question ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't those requests dynamic? So how is the URL being changed?

Comment: You may need to check this [website](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: @MaxZoom Absolutely no one needs to visit [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/). Please use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) for linking documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript encodeURIComponent when passing parameters in your ajax request, this will properly encode the user data.

Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent